# is there a way to write the code shorther?

Tags: php

im trying to make a calculator for school, and this is my code. is it possible to write it shorter? i feel like i can make this even better. Also im new to php and trying to learn and write it clean.

```html
<html>
<h1>Kortingsprijs berekenen</h1>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <label>Prijs in Euro's</label>
        <input type="text" name="prijs" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['prijs'])) {echo $_POST['prijs'];} ?>">
        <br>
        <input class="kortingProcent" type="radio" name="korting" value="20" />20%
        <br>
        <input class="kortingProcent" type="radio" name="korting" value="30" />30%
        <br>
        <input class="kortingProcent" type="radio" name="korting" value="40" />40%
        <br>
        <input class="kortingProcent" type="radio" name="korting" value="50" />50%
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Berekenen" value="Berekenen"/>
    </form>
</html>
</strike>
```

Comment: yes, there is a way to make that code shorter

Comment: Note that if your code _works_ then Stackoverflow is the wrong place to ask. Please post this over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: It looks fine for this. If you wanted to make it more versatile, you'd define the `%` values, and then 1. generate the form to match, and 2. evaluate to match. Make it generic. You can also `echo $_POST['prijs'] ?? ''` for the form value to trim the little bits, but that has little to do with elegance here. If you run into trouble creating an abstracted and more compact version of this, please feel free to ask again.

Comment: Really though, you can just calculate the % from any input value instead of using a switch with explicit cases.

Comment: @Flash Thunder I'm sorry it may be weird, is there any exchange site for asking how to learn something or how to edit some plugins like WYSIWYG? or a general code asking will work?

Comment: Sorry i did not know that next time ill ask on codereview.stackexchange.com instead. my bad. thank you guys for your help, next time when its more complex ill surely ask for more help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$korting` should also give a correct output when it is not 20,30,40 or 50, but -- for example -- 25 (even though it is not available in your HTML form), just make the formula generic. And, as your code is focused on producing a value for `$bericht`, you could use the ternary conditional operator:

```
$prijs = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prijs', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
$korting = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'korting', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$bericht = !isset($_POST['Berekenen']) ? "Je hebt niks ingevuld!"
         : ($prijs === false  ? "Vul een prijs in euro's in! "
           : (is_null($korting) ? "Vul een Korting in!"
             : "Dit is de prijs met $korting% korting: € " .
               number_format((float)$prijs * (1 - $korting / 100.0), 2, '.', '')
             )
           );
```

Comment: Oke thank you for your help, ill try to use this instead :)

Comment: Thank you for your help :), i see how you have done it and ill try to implement this in my project :)